# How to make Spotlight index shell script wrapper applications?

Tags: spotlight, script

You can create executable Application Bundles containing a script with the same name (e.g. `Example.app` and `Example.app/Example`).

Unfortunately, these applications do not seem to get indexed by Spotlight.

Automator does make it easy to wrap scripts as applications, but it does not find applications that are not in the default path (e.g. `wine` installed via `homebrew`). Sourcing shell init files does not seem to help with that, and while I could use absolute paths, I'd rather have the scripts be portable.

I would prefer to understand and fix the underlying problem than having to use another tool like [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus).

Comment: Maybe this- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MDImporters/Concepts/WritingAnImp.html as a starting point?

Comment: Here's a pretty detailed breakdown how to do it in Tex. What does `mdls` show for your files you want to index? Just edit that in your post body and then @ me here if I don't see the update. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206328/how-to-search-latex-documents-in-spotlight

Comment: @fd0 thank you for the pointer, but this seems to be to support file types, not applications.

Comment: @bmike thank you for the pointer! `mdls` helped me find differences between Emacs and my Spacemacs Bundle. Copying the `Info.plist` from Emacs and adjusting the executable name in it - which I forgot to do last time I tried and copied that file - turned out to work. I could not work out what exactly in that file was needed, but in this case, this solves my problem, and I'll know where to look more if need be.

Comment: Perfect. Glad you've made progress - it's great if you want to pop a proper answer explaining what you did and then marking the accepted tick. You can always take away the "answered" check if you want more answers to this.