# Why are almost-blank ._ files being created by macOS and applications?

Tags: macos

Using information found on this site and across the web, I have discovered how to transform most of the binary data in a ._ file to readable text.

However, most of the files that I have examined look like this:

```
Mac OS X       "
        @
ATTR
This resource fork intentionally left blank
```

After reading another Ask Different question and the Matt Deatherage explanation that Graham Perrin linked to in [his answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them#answer-51147), I am still quite confused. Especially considering that Matt said this:

> Note that "._MyFile" is *not* "a resource fork", and *not* "metadata", but could contain either or both of these.  It contains *anything* that
>   the Mac OS X file system supports but the volume's own format does not.
>   You rarely see "._" files on HFS Plus because HFS Plus supports all the
>   metadata that Apple has defined, now or in the past.  You see a lot of
>   them on UFS, FAT16, or other old formats that don't support rich
>   metadata because the OS has to put this stuff *someplace*.
>
> ...
>
> IF YOU DELETE ._MyFile OR SIMILAR COMPANION FILES, YOU ERASE ACTUAL FILE
>   SYSTEM DATA THAT A PROGRAM ON YOUR SYSTEM HAS EXPLICITLY SET.
>
> ...
>
> If you want to move the disk back to your Macintosh and have the files
>   all work properly, I strongly recommend that you leave companion files
>   alone.  Deleting companion files is corrupting the file.

Wow...sounds like those files are pretty damn important according to Matt! Yet upon inspection, I have tons of them (mostly videos that I've played **once** on this Mac through VLC) that say nothing more than "this resource fork intentionally left blank".

So why the heck are these being created?! Am I missing something that **is** important by running `xxd -p /Volumes/Videos/._<Name of movie file> | sed 's/00//g' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\([0-9A-F]\{2\}\)/0x\1 /g' | xxd -r -p | strings | sed 's/ptb[LN]ustr//g'` on the offending files?

Comment: There isn't enough info here to tell quite what's going on; a dump of the text content of the file is not going to show everything. My recommendation: use the Finder to move some of the files to a native Mac volume (HFS+ or APFS) (this will cause it to convert the metadata to native form), then run `xattr -l <Name of movie file>`, and see what attributes it lists.

Comment: You get those empty versions when a program uses a file API that intentionally tries a bunch of things ahead of time, even if it turns out the program using the api won’t actually use it. This includes xattrs, forks and alternate streams. Most common on network shares and removable media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, these days it's pretty rare for there's files to contain anything of much importance, though it is possible a piece of software might choose to do so.

Historically it wasn't too uncommon for a file to have both a data and a resource fork, application binaries especially did this. I can't think of any modern software that uses a resource fork anymore though, so it's unlikely this is why you are seeing these files. [Most of the API's are long deprecated, and Apple doesn't recommend using it to store arbitrary data.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork#How_a_resource_fork_is_accessed)

You can check for such content on a file using `cat filename/..namedfork/rsrc | xxd` (on the main file, not the ._ file), though it might be necessary to move it to an HFS or APFS file system first, not sure. The `xattr` CLI tool should show it too.

The main thing these files are used for currently is storing extended attributes ([which have some size limitations](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88752/is-there-a-maximum-length-of-metadata-that-can-be-written-in-one-xattr-command)). Things like Gatekeeper quarantine info, last line and column edited in a text editor, or resume time in a video player.

You can inspect this information using the `xattr` CLI tool, though it might be necessary to move it to an HFS or APFS file system first, not sure.

Comment: You said, "These days it's pretty rare for there's files to contain anything of importance." Would you please site some authoritative source for this comment you've made.

Comment: @user3439894 I'm mostly speaking from experience. I've adjusted the sentence to make that clear.

Comment: I have several apps the make use of ._filename.ext files, one of the being Apple's Safari, which for downloaded files writes several pieces of information to the ._filename.ext files, like the download date, where downloaded from, date added, as well as the com.apple.quarantine attribute. Which except for the last one mentioned, I like have this information.

Comment: @user3439894 - Good for you; you're getting value out of these files and I am happy for you. But I (and assumably **a lot** of people) don't give a crap about the download date etc., yet it is forced upon us to have these garbage files on our system. In the words of Mr. Horse - "Uhh...no sir, I don't like it!!" :P

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I expected - that these files are nothing but garbage in this day and age, yet Apple and app devs still insist on using them. +15 to you sir!